# Git shows a deleted file, but gives error when trying to git rm

Tags: git

Git shows me this when I do `git status`

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    spec/game_spec.rb
```

When I try `$ git rm spec/game_spec.rb` I get this error: `fatal: pathspec 'spec/game_spec.rb' did not match any files`.

When I try `$ git checkout spec/game_spec.rb` I get this error: `error: pathspec 'spec/game_spec.rb' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

What is going on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You `rm spec/game_spec.rb` before.

If you want to get it back, use `git checkout -- spec/game_spec.rb` (Note that you cannot skip **--** )

Answer (score -2):

Try to use next:

```
git add -u

git commit -m "some message"

git push
```